# How to make ui-view="ui-view" to ui-view in html using Jade

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, pug

I tried implementing angular ui router in Node JS using Jade Template Engine.

But the ui view isnt appearing like it use to in HTML.
Following is my code in Jade :

```
body(ng-app="mainapp")
h1!= message
div.row 
        div.col-md-4.col-md-offset-4
                a(ui-sref="todo") To Do App
                a(ui-sref="chat") Chat Room 
    div.row
            div.col-lg-12(ui-view)
```

It Renders HTML as

```
<body ng-app="mainapp">
<h1></h1>
<div class="row"> 
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4"><a ui-sref="todo">To Do App</a><a ui-sref="chat">Chat Room </a></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div ui-view="ui-view" class="col-lg-12">   </div>
</div>
```

I want to remove the ui-view="ui-view" to just **ui-view**
Render output as :

```
  <div ui-view class="col-lg-12">   </div>
```

How to achieve that

Comment: did you try it as a tag instead of attribute?

Comment: tag works , such attributes with values isnt supported by Jade ?

Comment: Not sure, I never use jade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use

```
doctype html
```

on top of your jade file.

Or just go with an empty attribute (which mostly works with angular, I don't know exactly if it works with ui-view).

```
div.col-lg-12(ui-view="")
```

Comment: actually i tried div.col-lg-12(ui-view="") but it didnt either. 
Thanks setting doctype html made it worked.

Comment: Here's a github ticket describing the problem: https://github.com/jadejs/jade/issues/370